# Nominally, he has only half a life at 59! - British cryptic crossword question

Tags: cryptic-crosswords

I [believe](https://puzzling.meta.stackexchange.com/a/235/63432) cryptic crossword questions are valid here, though do forgive me if I'm wrong!

> NOMINALLY, HE HAS ONLY HALF A LIFE AT 59! (5)

The "(5)" denotes the amount of letters in the answer.

HINT:

> From the *nominally* part, I believe that the answer is a name, though I'm not sure why.

What's the answer, and why?

Comment: That's quite a long life: $277366237091379671475878039440778812691805753545374865081642589880320000000000000$.

Comment: @WhatsUp I don't get your comment??

Comment: @smci 59! (that is, the factorial of 59) is 1.366*10^80. But that's only half his life, so the full life is twice as much: 2.77*10^80

Comment: @legrojan. Ah, right. My brain skipped the '!'

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Your instinct is correct - the answer is indeed a five-letter name, clued by '*Nominally, **he***' (so you are looking for a **male** name, specifically). It is:

> **FELIX**

Why?

> 'Half a life' gives you 'FE' (literally, the second half of the four-letter word 'LIFE'). Fifty-nine in Roman numerals is 'LIX'. Put them together, and voila!

Comment: Thanks! I think this is definitely correct. And my own name, as well, as a bonus!

Comment: @Lordology Whaaaaa'?!! Now that is a super weird coincidence...!

Comment: Given the solution, I think "before 59" would have been a better way to write the puzzle than "at 59".

Comment: I would have expected an element with an atomic half life of 59 units of time like... *googles* Titanium 44.

Comment: @nick012000, that wouldn't be a [cryptic clue](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cryptic_crossword#How_cryptic_clues_work).

Comment: I was hoping it would be one of the two guys from the 118 118 adverts. :)